# SAS macro looping by date, how to indicate the correct step?

Tags: date, sas, sas-macro, do-loops

I need to create 3 SAS tables for years, quarters and months which would encompass a designated range from the today's date. I guess there is a smarter way to do it, but I ended up with something like (say, if I need to go 5 years back):

```
    %macro asd;

%let today = %sysfunc(today());
%let end_year = %sysfunc(intnx(year,&today,-5));


proc sql;
create table years
(
Years num informat = date9. format = date9.
);

insert into years

%do i = &today. %to &end_year. %by -365;
%if i = &today.-365 %then %do;
values(&i.-1)
%end;
%else %do;
values(&i.) 
%end;
%end;
;
quit;

%mend asd;
%asd;
run;
```

The problem is that I don't know how to indicate a step in the loop as a date period, so I ended up with exact numbers, which vary (for year - every 4 years, for month - every second month, for quarters - every 16 quarters).

I added a loop for a year to try and account at least for several leap years, but it doesn't work. So before proceeding to months and probably implementing another nested looping I wanted to ask if there is an easier way to create such tables?

Thanks! :)

Comment: Can you show the data you want to generate?  Examples of how you want to store the date periods would help explain what you are trying to do.  If you just want to generate ranges of dates then you can probably do it in a data step and avoid macro code and SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your loop to loop over the number of years and calculate the macro variable needed inside the loop instead.

Example - non macro version.

```
 Do I=1 to 5;
     Year=intnx('year', date, 1);

      Rest of code;
 End;
```

Comment: Thanks! I have rewritten the loop and it works :)
`%do i = -1 %to -5 %by -1;

values(%sysfunc(intnx(year,&today.,&i.)))

%end;`.